# How do I add up all the numbers from all the fields using Django aggregate?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a model and the model has fields. For each record I have several fields that store numbers.

I want to know the total of ALL the numbers of all the fields of all the records.

So...

Record one: field_one: 1, field_two: 2, field_three: 5
Record two: field_one:2, field_two: 4, field_three: 0

The total would be: 14

I've been trying something like:

`return models.Model.objects.aggregate(numer=Sum('field_one', 'field_two', 'field_three'))`

and then the output with `{{ object.number }}`

I expect 14.

However, it's not showing me anything. I THINK I'm just adding up each field for each record and then I have the object total of field_1 to 3.

Any ideas on how to get the complete total?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: Django 1.8. Is there something new in it that I missed?

Comment: I know that 1.8 made aggregations and annotations a whole lot more useful. And if you were using an older version, such as 1.4, it might be much more difficult. I can't say specifically what may have change though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
return models.Model.objects.aggregate(number=(Sum('field_one') + Sum('field_two') + Sum('field_three')))
```